# Grpc service cannot receive any request with linkerd

Tags: .net, kubernetes, grpc, linkerd

I'm trying to integrate Linkerd with my grpc service on kubernetes for load balance problem according to [this article](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/11/07/grpc-load-balancing-on-kubernetes-without-tears/) , but my grpc service cannot receive any request when working with Linkerd and the grpc client freeze, throwing no exception. Both service and client are .Net Core app and use insecure credential.

I made some tests. The grpc server can work without Linkerd and Linkerd can work with ASP.NET Core web api.

I followed official instruction: [Getting Started](https://linkerd.io/2/getting-started/) and [Adding Your Service](https://linkerd.io/2/adding-your-service/). Here is the generated yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: demogrpc
  name: demogrpc
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demogrpc
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        linkerd.io/created-by: linkerd/cli stable-2.1.0
        linkerd.io/proxy-version: stable-2.1.0
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: demogrpc
        linkerd.io/control-plane-ns: linkerd
        linkerd.io/proxy-deployment: demogrpc
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: GRPC_HOST
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: SERVICE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: GRPC_PORT
          value: "8000"
        image: 192.168.99.25:30000/demogrpchost:1.0.9
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: demogrpc
        resources: {}
      - env:
        - name: LINKERD2_PROXY_LOG
          value: warn,linkerd2_proxy=info
        - name: LINKERD2_PROXY_BIND_TIMEOUT
          value: 10s
        - name: LINKERD2_PROXY_CONTROL_URL
          value: tcp://linkerd-proxy-api.linkerd.svc.cluster.local:8086
        - name: LINKERD2_PROXY_CONTROL_LISTENER
          value: tcp://0.0.0.0:4190
        - name: LINKERD2_PROXY_METRICS_LISTENER
          value: tcp://0.0.0.0:4191
        - name: LINKERD2_PROXY_OUTBOUND_LISTENER
          value: tcp://127.0.0.1:4140
        - name: LINKERD2_PROXY_INBOUND_LISTENER
          value: tcp://0.0.0.0:4143
        - name: LINKERD2_PROXY_DESTINATION_PROFILE_SUFFIXES
          value: .
        - name: LINKERD2_PROXY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: gcr.io/linkerd-io/proxy:stable-2.1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /metrics
            port: 4191
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
        name: linkerd-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4143
          name: linkerd-proxy
        - containerPort: 4191
          name: linkerd-metrics
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /metrics
            port: 4191
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 2102
        terminationMessagePolicy: FallbackToLogsOnError
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: kubernetes-registry
      initContainers:
      - args:
        - --incoming-proxy-port
        - "4143"
        - --outgoing-proxy-port
        - "4140"
        - --proxy-uid
        - "2102"
        - --inbound-ports-to-ignore
        - 4190,4191
        image: gcr.io/linkerd-io/proxy-init:stable-2.1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: linkerd-init
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
            - NET_ADMIN
          privileged: false
        terminationMessagePolicy: FallbackToLogsOnError
status: {}
```

And here is the log message from one of the linkerd-proxy:

```
INFO linkerd2_proxy::app::main using controller at Some(Name(NameAddr { name: DnsName(DNSName("linkerd-proxy-api.linkerd.svc.cluster.local")), port: 8086 }))
INFO linkerd2_proxy::app::main routing on V4(127.0.0.1:4140)
INFO linkerd2_proxy::app::main proxying on V4(0.0.0.0:4143) to None
INFO linkerd2_proxy::app::main serving Prometheus metrics on V4(0.0.0.0:4191)
INFO linkerd2_proxy::app::main protocol detection disabled for inbound ports {25, 3306}
INFO linkerd2_proxy::app::main protocol detection disabled for outbound ports {25, 3306}
WARN 10.244.1.137:8000 linkerd2_proxy::proxy::reconnect connect error to Config { target: Target { addr: V4(10.244.1.137:8000), tls: None(InternalTraffic), _p: () }, settings: Http2, _p: () }: Connection refused (os error 111) (address: 127.0.0.1:8000)
```

How do I make my grpc service work with Linkerd? Or is there better solution to load balance grpc service in kubernetes?

Comment: I am going to take a wild guess here, what if you specify the grpc_host variable as 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 or localhost  my understanding of linkerd is that it will talk to your service via 127.0.0.1.  disclaimer: i've not tried linkerd2 yet.

Comment: You're right. The linkerd is now able to connect to  grpc service with 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I just added the answer in case other people come across such issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By specifying GRPC_HOST to 127.0.0.1 allows Linkerd to connect to the grpc server.  Since linkerd proxy will use loopback address to connect to the other containers in this case the grpc service.